# How to throw an custom Exception by an resource to error.jsp from filter

Tags: exception, filter

When we forward to resource from filter, we are using either RequestDispatcher or FilterChain > doFilter method. and I have used FilterChain doFilter in my code, because it forwards to resource (if filter not found in descriptor) otherwise filter.

I wrapped this FilterChain doFilter call within try catch block, and filter only throws ServletException or IOException, can i able to throw any custom Exception (thrown by my action classes) from filter, instead of throwing ServletException. am i doing anything wrong. Please advise me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                 ServletResponse response,
                 FilterChain chain) 
                 throws java.io.IOException, ServletException,WIUException {


      String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

      if(ipAddress != null){
          throw new WIUException("It is an WIU Exception");
      }
       chain.doFilter(request,response);
   }
```

Here WIUException is a custom Exception.This may helpful to you check.

Comment: I already have this kind of custom exception, but i could not able to throw this exception from filter, because filter only throws servlet Exception....

Comment: I changed my answer for your scenario, check this it may helpful to you

Comment: chain.doFilter forwards to either resource or filter, If it forwarded to resource, and it will throw an exception if resource throws any exception... right???

Comment: Yes. Else you can catch that exception and do some action accordingly `catch (WIUExceptione) {httpResponse.sendRedirect(contextPath+"/jsp/LoginUser.cactus");}`